# Ways of comparing Dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
vd = {'Klein': [1,1,1], 'Fox-Epstein': [1,-1,0], 'Ravella': [-1,0,0]}
```

I need a procedure that iterates over the dictionary checking which entry is most similar to one provided as an argument. I have two procedures the first is nested in the second.

```
def policy_compare(sen_a, sen_b, voting_dict):
    a = 0
    for i in range(len(voting_dict[sen_a])):
        a += voting_dict[sen_a][i] * voting_dict[sen_b][i]
    return a
```

This returns the dot product of two of the selected entries.

```
def most_similar(sen, voting_dict):
    a = []
    for i in voting_dict.keys():
        score = policy_compare(sen,i, voting_dict)
        a += score
    return a
```

The second procedure is not complete for two reasons:

1. At the moment it is returning an error and I can't see where I am going wrong.
2. It just returns a list of the dot products (The one with the greatest dot product in the most similar), whereas I require the 'key' who's scalar product with the chosen sen is largest.

FULL error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    most_similar('Klein', vd)
  File "/Users/anthony/Desktop/matrix/megalol.py", line 15, in     most_similar
a += score
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Add the traceback of the error it is returning

Comment: A less vague title if you can think of it wouldn't be bad either.  Something specific to your error or problem, maybe.

Comment: `if i == sen: pass` doesn't do anything. That's not your problem, but I thought you should know.

Comment: I put it in because i thought that, if compared to itself then it would return the dot product with itself, and i don't want that. haha. But thanks, it's gone from my post, some code wizard has removed it i'm guessing. :P

Comment: Include the **full** error please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some modifications to approach the solution you want:

```
vd = {'Klein': [1,1,1], 'Fox-Epstein': [1,-1,0], 'Ravella': [-1,0,0]}

def policy_compare(sen_a, sen_b, voting_dict):
    a = 0
    for i in range(len(voting_dict[sen_a])):
        a += voting_dict[sen_a][i] * voting_dict[sen_b][i]
    return a

def most_similar(sen, voting_dict):
    a = []
    for this_sen in voting_dict.keys():
        if this_sen == sen:
            continue
        score = policy_compare(sen, this_sen, voting_dict)
        a.append((this_sen, score))
    return max(a,key=lambda sen: sen[1])

print most_similar('Klein', vd)
```

As someone else has said, you want to `append` to your list `a`. I've added the senator's name along with the dot product in a tuple (for each item in `a`) because the dictionary keys come out in arbitrary order and you won't know which one is being referred to by each entry in `a` otherwise. I've returned the maximum dot product entry from `most_similar`. Also, to avoid comparing senators with themselves you want to use `continue` (go back to the start of the loop for the next iteration), not `pass` (do nothing and continue with the current iteration).

Comment: I was just about to post my solution, i had a brain wave. Thanks a bunch +1

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a list, `score` is an int.  You can't add the two together.  A list is iterated over in order to get the contents in order to add them to another - thus the "weird" error.  It can't iterate over the int (score) in order to add it to the the list (a).

try `a.append(score)` to add score on to the end of it.

Comment: No problem. I hope you found a full solution to your problem.  Sometimes error messages can tell you exactly what you need to know - if only you knew what they meant!